# Python Set task

Tags: python

My task is to write Python code that proves this equality: `A∩(B \ C) = (A∩ B)\ (A∩C)(А,В,С - these are sets)`.
I decided to do each action separately and then add the results obtained.
hat is:

1. A∩(B \ C) расписываю в виде кода и выполняю
2. (A∩ B)\ (A∩C) write in the form of code and execute
3. I compare the results obtained and if they are the same I output True, if not - False

And so I write a code to perform 1 action and check it:

```
A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} 
B = {4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
C = {2,4,6,8,10}

A.intersection_update(B.difference_update(C))
print(A)
```

And in the end I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\artem\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Bot3\Lab3.py", line 5, in <module>
A.intersection_update(B.difference_update(C))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `B.difference_update(C)` doesn't return anything - it just modifies `B`. Have you tried using `B.difference(C)` instead? (this returns the modified list, instead of actually modifying `B`

Comment: Both `..._update()` methods return `None`

Comment: I'm not sure you can prove it. You can demonstrate it, but whether it's conclusive is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question in the comments.
You may simplify your syntax with:

```
A & (B - C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation,
[`set.intersection_update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.intersection_update) and [`set.difference_update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.difference_update) are in place operations and so do **not** return anything.

*Another hint would be that they are [augmented assignments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/).*

You should use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.intersection) and [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.difference) instead.